# What should I change so that when I click on the notification button, it closes?

Tags: android, kotlin

Last evening the notification was closing, but today I sat down to check and saw that the notification has stopped closing, what should I do?

```
private fun sendNotification(){


       val closeIntent = Intent(this, CloseNotificationReceiver::class.java)
           .putExtra("ID", notificationId)
       val closeFlag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
           PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE else 0
       val closePendingIntent = PendingIntent
           .getBroadcast(this, 0, closeIntent, closeFlag)

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        ///
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "400 мл", closePendingIntent)
        ////


       with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
           notify(notificationId, builder.build())
```

---

```
class CloseNotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val id = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0)
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel(id)
}}
```

---

```
<receiver
        android:name=".CloseNotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/emblema" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Create additional action button and `PendingIntent`

```
val closeIntent = Intent(this, CloseNotificationReceiver::class.java)
    .putExtra("ID", notificationId)
val closeFlag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE else 0
val closePendingIntent = PendingIntent
    .getBroadcast(this, requestCode, closeIntent, closeFlag)

val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    // ...
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_close, "Close", closePendingIntent)
    // ...

NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
    .notify(notificationId, builder.build())
```

#### Then implement `BroadcastReceiver` to handle closing `Intent`s

```
class CloseNotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val id = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0)
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel(id)
    }
}
```

And declare the receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".CloseNotificationReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: why it doesnt work, and what I should write instead of requestCode?

Comment: Don't you forget to add the receiver to `AndroidManifest.xml`? I've supplemented my answer with code in the manifest. If the problem will still persist, please provide the full code of your notification builder.

Answer (score 1):

I think you maybe want to call

```
.setAutoCancel(true)
```

on your `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Comment: I did this, but when I press the button in the notification it does not disappear

Comment: it disappears if I click on the notification itself and not on the button in it